# REACT NATIVE : How to render component on top of the ios native video player

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to render the component on top of the video player in my react native app. I am seeing that component correctly in the Android app but unable to see it in the ios app. Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's impossible to help you without code and/or demo, but in general components listed later will be rendered on top of components rendered before (in the `render()` function)